# Laravel 5 RequestForm Validation with nested selects

Tags: php, jquery, validation, laravel, request

I have a Form with 2 nested selects.

For example: Department has Many Sections.

When submit the Form, requestForm validation is executed, and if validation result failed, return to the Form and autocomplete fields with post data.

But the section, is not filled with current selected, it's reseted to first item of de list.

The question is, how can set the current section selected when requestForm return failed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution using Request::old.

```
public function getCreate() {
  $department = \Request::old('department_id');
  $departments = \App\Models\RRHH\Department::lists('description', 'id');
  if($department != '') {
    $sections = \App\Models\RRHH\Department::find($department)->section->lists('description', 'id');
  } else {
    $sections = [];
  }
    .....
}
```